# How can I fix an undefined symbol when using "LoopInfo::getLoopFor"?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to write a pass that go through each basic block, and I want to identify whether each basic block is in a loop or not.

I added `LoopInfo` as a required analysis:

```cpp
virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
    AU.setPreservesCFG();
    AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
    AU.addPreserved<LoopInfo>();
}
```

And then called `getLoopFor`:

```cpp
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &Func) {
    OptimizeBB(bb);
    return false;
}

virtual void OptimizeBB(BasicBlock &bb){
    LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfo>();
    errs()<<" \nDebug Here\n ";
    Loop* innerloop=LI.getLoopFor(&bb);
    if(innerloop==NULL){ errs()<<" \n(not loop)\n ";}
    else { errs()<<" \n(loop)\n ";}
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> /home/mypass/llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/opt: symbol lookup error: /home/mypass/llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/ReadIR.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm12LoopInfoBaseINS_10BasicBlockENS_4LoopEE10getLoopForEPKS1_

How can I fix that? Or is there any other method that can identify a loop for a basic block?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the correct headers included. In the following code, what are you passing as `bb` ?

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &Func) {
OptimizeBB(bb);
return false;
}
```

You need to iterate over `Func` to get the BBs within `Func` and then pass them to `OptimizeBB()`.

Comment: It's a basicblock ( Basicblock *bb )

Comment: @IanTsai Try commenting out the following extern declarations in LoopInfo.h, and build on root llvm directory.

\_\_extension\_\_ extern template class LoopBase<BasicBlock, Loop>;
\_\_extension\_\_ extern template class LoopInfoBase<BasicBlock, Loop>;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &Func) {
     for (Function::iterator I = F.begin(), E = F.end(); I != E; ++I)
          OptimizeBB(bb);
     return false;
}
```